# In FirebaseUI for iOS, forcing dark mode causes the Apple Icon to blend in with the background

Tags: ios, swift, firebaseui, ios-darkmode

I am using `FirebaseUI` for iOS. The "Sign In With Apple" icon is blending in with the background.

I am forcing dark mode like so:

```
HomeView()
  .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
```

When the OS is set to light mode, the buttons look like this:

[image]

My app is not getting approved because:

*It is not clear that the Sign in with Apple button is a button. It should be clear to the user what is and isn't a button in your user interface.*

Anyone know how to make the Apple icon white when forcing dark mode on an iPhone set to light mode?

Comment: You are not using the right tags.

Comment: What tags should I use?